# Keep latest result from partitioned data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some package that is preparing query for columns for data. In one of the cases for data as below, snippet: `... max(DISTINCT ALTERNATIVE_ID) over (partition by ENVELOPE_ID order by CREATED desc) ...` returned two rows which crashed the call.

| ID | POSITION_ID | ALTERNATIVE_ID | ALTERNATIVE_ID_TYPE | ENVELOPE_ID | CREATED | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | position_1 | ALT_1 | ENV_1 | TYPE | 25-07-2021 | 5 |
| 2 | position_1 | ALT_2 | ENV_1 | NEW_TYPE | 26-07-2021 | -5 |

When I change the snippet to: `...max(DISTINCT ALTERNATIVE_ID) keep(DENSE_RANK first oreder by CREATED) over (PARTITION BY ENVELOPE_ID) ...` in integration test I've got

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Can You get only the latest 'ALTERNATIVE_ID' and 'ALTERNATIVE_ID_TYPE' always for this duplicated cases with aggregation functions in oracle, or do I have to create some other query to get the first row from these results? For example:

```
select *
from (select max(DISTINCT ALTERNATIVE_ID) over (partition by ENVELOPE_ID order by CREATED desc) from table)
where rownum = 1
```

The expected results with a correct snippet in the whole call would look like this:

| ID | POSITION_ID | ALTERNATIVE_ID | ALTERNATIVE_ID_TYPE | ENVELOPE_ID | CREATED | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | position_1 | **ALT_2** | ENV_1 | **NEW_TYPE** | 25-07-2021 | 5 |
| 2 | position_1 | **ALT_2** | ENV_1 | **NEW_TYPE** | 26-07-2021 | -5 |

Comment: I think I follow your question until the very end, where you show a table with two rows.  Everything else suggests (to me) that you want one row in the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff To be more precise, I want to avoid changing the data, just want from this query to return latest alts to avoid deprecated alt type in results to external client. I will add more data to better show why I want to keep both records as a result.

Comment: You table is *apparently* not in the *normal form*. The column `ENVELOP_ID` is not dependent *solely* on the *primary key* column (which is causing your troubles). You mast tell us from which column *it is dependent* to be able to help you. This could be `POSITION_ID` or `ALTERNATIVE_ID` or `ALTERNATIVE_ID_TYPE`  or some combination of those. Without this information only *gusses* are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an analytic function with the `KEEP` clause:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       POSITION_ID,
       MAX(alternative_id)
         KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY created)
         OVER (PARTITION BY alternative_id_type) AS alternative_id,
       ALTERNATIVE_ID_TYPE,
       MAX(envelope_id)
         KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY created)
         OVER (PARTITION BY alternative_id_type) AS envelope_id,
       CREATED,
       AMOUNT
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  ID,
  POSITION_ID,
  ALTERNATIVE_ID,
  ALTERNATIVE_ID_TYPE,
  ENVELOPE_ID,
  CREATED,
  AMOUNT
) AS
SELECT 1, 'position_1', 'ALT_1', 'ENV_1', 'TYPE',     DATE '2021-07-25',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'position_1', 'ALT_2', 'ENV_1', 'NEW_TYPE', DATE '2021-07-26', -5 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | ID | POSITION_ID | ALTERNATIVE_ID | ALTERNATIVE_ID_TYPE | ENVELOPE_ID | CREATED | AMOUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | position_1 | ALT_2 | ENV_1 | NEW_TYPE | 2021-07-26T00:00:00Z | -5 |
> | 1 | position_1 | ALT_2 | ENV_1 | NEW_TYPE | 2021-07-25T00:00:00Z | 5 |

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/685e6/5)*

Answer (score 0):

> Can You get only the latest 'ALTERNATIVE_ID' and 'ALTERNATIVE_ID_TYPE' always for this duplicated cases with aggregation functions in oracle, or do I have to create some other query to get the first row from these results?

If I understand correctly, you can use `fetch first`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by created desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: This would need another query to get only this two values and insert them through the function that is creating the query. But is it possible to get the same result with aggregation functions in the same call?